# hybridauth redirection to an emailed link after success login

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization

Im using [hybridauth](https://www.drupal.org/project/hybridauth) to let users login from different social media websites ...
I send emails manually to some users with an link to edit specific nodes (for example http://example.com/node/444/edit?parma1=val1&param2=val2).
At that moment the user is automatically redirected to a page to choose a social media he want to login with.
Im using hook_init for this :

```
function MYMODULE_init(){
  if($node->type == 'type' && other conditions){
    drupal_goto('link_to_hybridauth_login_page'); 
  }
}
```

Now I want that user to be automatically redirected to that link sent via email after success login via hybridauth ( I tried to add destination query inside drupal_goto but not working.)

how can I do this redirection ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How did you try to add the 'destination' query? It should be something like this:

```
$query_array = array('param1' => 'value1', 'destination' => 'original_path');
$options = array(
  'query' => query_array,
);
drupal_goto('link_to_hybridauth_login_page', $options);
```

Basically, it's important that the destination is passed as part of the $options['query'].

If that doesn't work, try and add your own hook_user_login(), to pick up the 'destination' (or whatever parameter you want to use for the original URL, and redirect the user accordingly). Like:

```
if (isset($_GET['destination'])) {
  drupal_goto($_GET['destination']);
}
```

You can see an example implementation of hook_user_login in the user_homepage module code: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/user_homepage/tree/user_homepage.module?id=6803e00

Hope this helps with your problem.

**EDIT**: The hook_user_login() is meant to be something additional to the hook_init() logic you were trying, but not to replace it. Thought I'd just clarify that =).

**EDIT 2**: Ok, So if I'm getting the problem right, you need to get not only the 'node/xxx/edit' part of the URL, which you have already sorted (right?) but you need to also get all the params of the incoming URL.

Basically, you need to use drupal_get_query_parameters() for that. So you could assemble the $options array like this:

```
  $current_query_params = drupal_get_query_parameters();
  // Pick up URL and treat params as you need, and prepare query array with 
  // the 'destination' desired, assembled with data from $current_query_params.
  $new_query_array = array();  
  $options = array(
    'query' => $new_query_array,
  );
```

Hope I'm getting it right now. The linked drupal code from user_homepage uses these functions for a very similar scenario. Look at *user_homepage_build_homepage_path_from_request()* and *user_homepage_user_login()* functions.

Comment: the problem is not how do i use destination query, but how to pass this edit node url to this query ?

Comment: because when user try to connect via hybridauth, I can't access to this node anymore.